# @Subscribe method called multiple time for the same event

Tags: android, otto

In my code I'm listening for events using `@Subscribe` anotation:

```
@Subscribe
public void orderUpdate(OrderUpdateEvent event)
```

My problem is that this method is called multiple times (1-3 depends from run to run) for the same event object.

This is how I send this event:

```
busProvider.getEventBus().postOnMain(new OrderUpdateEvent();
```

What could be the cause of that? Do I'm missing something?

Comment: have you already found solution for you problem?

Comment: yes, as @CommonsWare suggested `unregister()` was not called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What could be the cause of that?

One possibility is that you have three instances of this class still registered on the event bus. Make sure that you `unregister()` when the object should no longer receive messages.

Comment: I have similar question: For example I received event in `@Subscribe` method, than I closed `Fragment` and unregistered Bus in method `onPause`. After that I opened `Fragment` again, registered Bus in method `onResume` and received the same event that I already handled before. I don't want to receive same Event every time I back to the `Fragment`. Any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: @vovaxo: I do not know how that would happen with Otto.

Comment: @vovaxo are you sure this is the same Event object?

Comment: @skywalker I'm sure. Maybe I have a bit different situation. I am sending event from `Service`